# Results of Randomized Button Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, random

I am trying to create a custom/random story generator.

I currently have a Pop-Up with 3 forms to fill out which will replace text of a story. When the user clicks "Brew", I want the Pop-up to close and the story results to be displayed in the second column of the second row. Currently the "Brew" button, when pressed, displays some text because of a function I wrote "displayJuice()", but not the text results of the form submission.

I am having trouble getting the results of the story to display anywhere on the page.

Here's my Javascript file:

```
function displayJuice() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.style.display = "block";
}

const customName = document.getElementById('customName');
const customFruit = document.getElementById('customFruit');
const customDiet = document.getElementById('customDiet');
const randomize = document.querySelector('.randomize');
const story = document.querySelector('.story');

function randomValueFromArray(array){
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
  return array[random];
}

let storyText = "This delicious Fruit juice was made personally for Name! It's made with 100% Organic and locally-grown, fresh ingredients. What's inside: Fruit, Diet, :insertX:, :insertY:, and :insertZ:.";
let insertX = ['Raspberry','Strawberry','Blueberry','Blackberry', 'Cranberry'];
let insertY = ['Orange','Lemon','Lime','Tangerine', 'Grapefruit', 'Clementine'];
let insertZ = ['Papaya','Mango','Peach','Pineapple', 'Pomegranate', 'Lychee'];

randomize.addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {
  let newStory = storyText;

  let xItem = randomValueFromArray(insertX);
  let yItem = randomValueFromArray(insertY);
  let zItem = randomValueFromArray(insertZ);

  newStory = newStory.replace(':insertx:',xItem);
  newStory = newStory.replace(':inserty:',yItem);
  newStory = newStory.replace(':insertz:',zItem);

  if(customName.value !== '') {
    const name = customName.value;
    newStory = newStory.replace('Name',name);
  }

  if(customFruit.value !== '') {
    const fruit = customFruit.value;
    newStory = newStory.replace('Fruit',fruit);
  }

  if(customDiet.value !== '') {
    const diet = customDiet.value;
    newStory = newStory.replace('Diet',diet);
  }


  story.textContent = newStory;
  story.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Here's the html of my modal:

```
    <!-- Pop Up Window -->
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Let's get your juice ready...</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal Content -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="customName">Your Name</label>
              <input id="customName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter your name"><br>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="customFruit">Favorite Fruit</label>
              <input id="customFruit" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Watermelon"><br>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="customDiet">Second Favorite Fruit</label>
              <input id="customDiet" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tangerine"><br>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Footer Buttons -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary randomize" onClick="displayJuice()">Brew</button>
          </div>


          <!-- End of Modal -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and lastly, here's the column I am trying to get the story to display in

```
<!-- Output Juice Creation -->


            <div class="col">
              <p class="story"></p> // THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE STORY TO DISPLAY

              <div id="output">
                <h1>Name, Your Juice is Ready!</h1>
   
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your code seems somewhat messy.  It's not clear exactly what part you are having problems with.  A smaller example that shows the exact problem your having would be helpful.  It took me a while to find the 'brew' button you mention in your question.  Why does it have both an 'onClick()' and an event handler set in code (the element you call 'randomize' in code)

Answer (score 0):

I realized the javascript was loading too soon, so I added defer:

```
<script src="js/scripts.js" defer></script>
```

I also changed the "insertx" elements to "insertX" for case sensitivity.

Now it is working.